# Does every node in a CouchDB cluster have copy of the data?

Tags: couchdb-2.x

More I read the documentation, more I get confused.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/cluster/theory.html

Let me put my question in simple way:

I have 3 nodes cluster having below configuration:
n=3, q=8

1. Would this configuration make sure that in case of failure of 2 nodes, 3rd node will have all the documents/data for read and write?
2. Does value of r and w will have any impact?
3. if I configure the value of r=1 and w=3 then will it make sure any node in cluster will have all documents/data stored in different shards.

Comment: Answer received from Joan Touzet:1) Yes, 2) not in the config file 3) no, n=3 q=8 ensures all 3 nodes have all docs split across 24 shards, 8 per.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer, and accept it, rather than in a comment. Comments are subject to deletion; by putting it in an answer, future visitors are sure to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer received from Joan Touzet:1) Yes, 2) not in the config file 3) no, n=3 q=8 ensures all 3 nodes have all docs split across 24 shards, 8 per.